# Apply gather function to multiple csv files, converting each input to an output file with a corresponding name in R

Tags: r, filenames, lapply, sink

I have a great number of csv files I have made into a list using the "list.files" function:

```
list.files("C:/Users/gyero/Documents/daphnia/SUMMARY_CHIMP")
```

I want to use the gather() function on each file and then sink() to produce a separate output for each csv file. I need some way to identify which output file corresponds to which input file.

To loop through files I had a crack at using lapply()

```
lapply(list.files[1:33], function{gather(WELL,MEASURE,A1:D6)})
```

I'm not sure how to get a corresponding output file name- so I tried preceding the lapply function with the following code so at least the output files would have a unique name and not get overwritten:

```
sink('DATA.CSV')
paste0(Sys.time(),'DATA.CSV')
```

However, I am very new to this and having trawled the internet I still can't realize my goal (the above didn't work). I would be MASSIVELY grateful to anyone who could spare the time to help a desperate noob out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
file_names <- list.files("C:/Users/gyero/Documents/daphnia/SUMMARY_CHIMP", 
                          full.names = TRUE)

lapply(file_names, function(x) {
    df <- read.csv(x)
    write.csv(tidyr::gather(df,WELL,MEASURE,A1:D6), 
              paste0(sub("\\.csv", "", basename(x)), "_output.csv"))
})
```

If you have files such as `"A.csv"`, `"B.csv"` in the folder, this will create new files with `"A_output.csv"`, `"B_output.csv"`. Also, note that `gather` has been retired and replaced with `pivot_longer` now.

Comment: Thank you soo much, this was incredibly helpful , I really appreciate it. I did notice that it only works on file names starting with the same number. Ie half my files have names starting with “24” and the other half “2” but it only processed the “24” files. I got around this by simply adding “24” to the front of all file names. Thank you again.